# Solving set of nonlinear equations with fsolve in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, optimization, scipy, ipython

Experiencing troubles with solving a list of nonlinear equations. So I am trying to do it in python with scipy.optimize.fsolve . 
The equation I have is the following

```
$$
-x^{(\alpha+1)}+a*\rho^2*x^\alpha+(1-\alpha)a(1-\rho^2)*(xm/(a(1-\rho)^2))^alpha
$$
```

where $\alpha$ , $\rho$ and $xm$ are parameters. I want to solve for $x$ for some $a$ drawn from lognormal. For that I write the python code as follows.

```
from scipy.optimize import *
from numpy.random import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


draws=[np.random.lognormal(1,0.5) for i in range(n)]
x_1=[fsolve(lambda x:(-x**(alpha+1)+a*rho**2*x**alpha+(1-alpha)*a*(1-rho**2)*(xm/(a*(1-rho)**2))**alpha),0) for a in draws]
```

No luck!. Can anybody help me out?

Comment: Are you getting an error message?  Or the wrong answer?

Comment: getting error message Cannot cast array data from dtype('O') to dtype('float64') according to the rule 'safe'

Comment: Please edit the question to include a complete example that we can copy and run to reproduce the problem.  Currently you don't show how you define `n`, `alpha`, `rho` and `xm`.  Also, include the complete traceback (i.e. the error message) in the question.

Comment: P.S. `numpy.random.lognormal` has a `size` argument, so you could write `draws = np.random.lognormal(1, 0.5, size=n)`.

Comment: Thanks for your replies, I will edit and repost the question, since it hasn't been solved yet